# Using fields from a table to return value to another field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database that I want to return a value based on the contents of two fields. I have detinations, and would like to return mileage that probably would be hard coded using Case.

Example: Case 1 Dest1 = "Savannah" and Dest2 ="Atlanta" 
             mileage = 248

I am new to VBA and seem to have trouble bringing in the field as a variable

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a more detailed question here. I'm guessing that you want to hard-code standard trip-mileages in a case statement. A much better design would be to place these standard mileages between end points in a table and look them up dynamically using the two end points as a key...